# Getting tier price value according to the different stores

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I want to put the tier data into some var.For this , I am getting Tier prices of a particular product through json_encode() function like this:

```
var tierPrices = <?php echo json_encode($_product->getTierPrice()) ?>;
    var getPrice = function(qty){
        qty = Number(qty);
        var i = tierPrices.length;
        while(i--)
        {
            if(qty >= tierPrices[i]['price_qty']){
                return tierPrices[i]['price'];
            }
        }
        return null;
    };


var price = getPrice(this.value);
```

What I need is get price value according to the different stores because it always pick up the tier price for default display store.I tried this:

```
var price = "<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency?>"+(getPrice(this.value));
```

But the value of tier price for both stores is coming same.
How the tier price will come according to the different stores currency.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the product according to the store id.

First you have to get the store id.

```
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```

And then load that product by the store id.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->load($key);
```

And then take the Tire price of that product.

```
$_product->getTierPrice();
```

Comment: This has not work for the Tier Prices.Same tier prices are coming, if the store id is '1' or if the store id is '2'.it is bringing the same array of prices.

Comment: $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
echo "store id is".$storeId;
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($storeId);
        $cpid = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();


$products->load($cpid);
$array = $products->getTierPrice();
print_r($array);

Comment: This is how i follow the code but it is printing out the same array when i open up the same product in both stores.

Comment: are you getting the different - different price or its a same price on every store...

Comment: it is the same price for every store

Comment: it is the same price for every store.As far as i know it will always show same price in the backend according to the DEFAULT DISPLAY CURRENCY.

Comment: Hmm...As we can see in the back-end this is not a GLOBAL attribute ...and if we make that as GLOBAL then it will not working as a global...as far i searched on Google i got that we cannot set the different different tire price according to the store.